# why Weka 3.8.6 is giving java error while open the tool?

Tags: java, weka

when I tried to run weka 3.8.6 the Error is

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) 
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) 
  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) 
  at weka.gui.SplashWindow.invokeMain(SplashWindow.java:306) 
  at weka.gui.GUIChooser.main(GUIChooser.java:92) 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
java.io.IOException: Unable to create the metastore directory: C:\Program Files\Weka-3-8-6\wekaMetaStore 
  at weka.core.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:134) 
  at weka.gui.LookAndFeel.setLookAndFeel(LookAndFeel.java:151) 
  at weka.gui.GUIChooserApp.main(GUIChooserApp.java:1663) 
  ... 6 more
```

Comment: You probably don't have write permission on `C:\Program Files\Weka-3-8-6`

Comment: i created environment variable for java. how can i get persmission?

Answer (score 1):

As [tgdavies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11002/tgdavies) pointed out, the currently logged in user does not seem to have write permissions to the `C:\Program Files\Weka-3-8-6` directory.

Did you create a `WEKA_HOME` environment variable and pointed it at the `C:\Program Files\Weka-3-8-6` directory? By default, this variable would point to `%USERPROFILE%\wekafiles` under Windows and `$HOME/wekafiles` under Linux/Mac.

The `WEKA_HOME` directory is not Weka's installation directory with the executables, javadoc, etc, but the directory where Weka will look for packages, props files, store its log files, etc.

You should create a directory in your home directory (your user would have write access there) and then point the `WEKA_HOME` environment variable to that directory. Once that is done, try starting Weka again.

Comment: Thank you i followed the same steps as u describe but didnt work

Comment: What directory did you create? In a command-prompt execute "echo %WEKA_HOME%" - is the output the same as the directory that you created? Do you have write access to that directory?

Comment: yes i write command on command prompt it was same then uninstall the weka latest version . Now i install 3.7.13 version it works. but when i am uploading the large file like 1 lac instances with 2 column then EOL error even when i decompose the data in order to check the error it works file. Note(i also increase the heap size using RUN.ini maxheap=2048M; javaOpts=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xmx1024m but it does not work

Comment: This is a different question, please start a new Q&A.

Comment: i have created the enviro. WEKA_HOME with weka home directory but i got same error as i mentioned earlier. what should i do ?

Comment: Update your question with: 1. the directory you installed Weka in. 2. the directory that will act as your Weka home dir. 3. the value of the WEKA_HOME environment variable (`echo %WEKA_HOME%`).